# Are there any rules for unix/linux shell variable naming?

Tags: linux, shell, variables, unix, syntax

Are there any rules for unix/linux shell variable naming?

For example, like the common rules for Java variable naming.

Comment: and also for the shell function name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script variable naming convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization/42290320#42290320)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be very careful not to use any UNIX command as a variable. It will mess the code and produce unexpected results. Also, keep in mind the reserved words (`if`, `else`, `elif`, `do`, `done`...) and that uppercase variables are reserved for system use.

From [Rules for Naming variable name](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Rules_for_Naming_variable_name):

> Variable name must begin with <s>alphanumeric</s> alpha character or underscore
>   character (_), followed by one or more alphanumeric or underscore
>   characters. Valid shell variable examples

Or as seen in [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231):

> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of
>   underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set.
>   The first character of a name is not a digit.

Comment: thanks for your response, i understand shell has its mandatory requirement about variable naming, i want to know do we have any recommendation about variable naming, for example: VAR_NAME or varName or var_name, which one is the best to use?

Comment: Shells expect variables to be preceded by `$`, so having a variable called `$ls` or `$done` (although initialised with `ls=1` or `done=1`) doesn't seem to cause problems - even if it looks confusing. Can you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: No, you can write it the way you prefer. The only suggestion I can  give you is to be constant on your decision, writing all the variables the same way: if you choose var_name, do always var_name and do not create any VarName or varName. It will help reading the code. But it is an esthetic decision, shell will not complain.

Comment: @BinaryZebra very good point. Thanks for the correction and the link. Updated!

Comment: This lacks an important detail from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization

Comment: @tripleee I am a bit out these days. Do you mean having them lowercase?

Comment: Yes, the fact that uppercase variables are reserved for system use.